# Login to a website/app without social login buttons

Tags: facebook, google, login, openid

Many Android apps request an account to use it, and many have the possibility to login via Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc via a button. Sometimes the apps have a desktop website and usually those websites have the same social login buttons to be able to login... but, what if those buttons are not present?

For example, I use Uber app in an Android smartphone, I login using the Google button, but their desktop websites does not feature the Google button, thus I can't login. How to do it?

Specifically, is it possible to login to websites without using those OpenID buttons that had been used before?

Comment: This is really going to depend on each specific website. There's no simple universal answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are absolutely right that this can be confusing sometimes. In case of Uber it is especially weird since the Google search result for 'Uber app login' shows

> Sign In. **Connect with Facebook**. or use email. Email. Password. Remember Me. Sign In. Forgot Password. Don't have an account? Sign Up.

and the Uber page itself does not offer this option. However to answer your question I have a trick I always use and it works most of the times.

When you create an account trough Facebook, Twitter or Google Plus your e-mailadres is still saved in the database of the website and most of the times a random username is also created for you.

So in order to log in to an interface without the possibility of a social login you could just request a password reset using a 'Forgot password' page. In that case you can create a password for your account and still log in.

I hope that works in your case!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try it when I face this problem again, yet about Uber it didn't helped me. It sends me an e-mail with a link to reset my password, but the link as soon as I click it it says it's not valid anymore, even if I clicked it right away. About the Facebook button, if you access Uber through the direct login link `https://login.uber.com/login` you can't see it. But through the main website `https://www.uber.com/en/log-in` an option to choose if you're a client or a driver makes appear the Facebook button.

Comment: But that's exactly what I don't want to do: allow an app with multiple accounts, like in this case Facebook. It's not that complicated to allow Facebook, but there must be a way, a generic way to login without the use of the buttons in multiple apps What the trick could be? Thanks for your answer (=